# Unable to do a query using a textbox input

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to allow user to enter details inside a textbox and use that information to run a SQL query. It works when I hard code everything for example:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE Name='Samuel'";
```

When I try to use the textbox instead as follows, it returns an error. I am definitely entering the correct name Samuel in the textbox. I ran a messagebox to check if the textbox is registering the name correctly and yes, it is correct. Please advice if you see anything wrong. Thanks.

```
name = textbox4.Text;
MessageBox.Show(name);
string query = "SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE Name=" + name;
```

Comment: [Im just going to leave this here...](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Little Bobby Tables strikes again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot quotes. Change query like below:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE Name='" + name + "'";
```

Comment: @keshk, incase you missed the relevance of my previous link, try entering into your textbox, the value of `';DROP TABLE PERSONS;`

Comment: @Sayse: or just **`"O'Reily"`**.  Or **`"A' OR '1'='1"`**.

Comment: Definitely, using an ORM tool or at least command parameters will be a better choice

Comment: @spencer7593 - Very nice, doesn't quite have the same *zing* to it

Comment: @Sayse I believe you are talking about SQL injections. I have set up a separate method to check that. As simple as it may seem, I was stuck with this problem of missing '' marks for over an hour thus I asked about it.

Answer (score 1):

What language? C#?

```
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE Name = '{0}'", SanitizeSql(name));
```

Or you could be cool and use https://github.com/markrendle/Simple.Data then it would just be

```
IEnumerable<Person> people = db.Persons.FindAllByName(name);
```

and this also takes care of SQL injection and is database independent (so you can switch from MSSQL to MySQL to MongoDB...)

Comment: +1. Wait, what? Sanitize user supplied input? Use a static SQL statement? A user is going to enter **`"O'Reilly"`** in the text box, and "I'm just gonna assume it all went to plan. What?" Dr. Evil style pinky finger to the corner of my mouth.

Comment: Haha I know. I use Simple.Data to handle all of the SQL injection prevention. It should be abstracted away to not slow down development.

Answer (score 0):

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE Name=" + name;
```

Should be

```
string query = "Select * From PERSONS Where name = '" + name + "'" ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`name=txbox.Text;`

`dbLog.Open("SELECT * FROM Persons WHERE Name='" & name & "'", dbCon, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenDynamic, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)`